# Prove that ${\omega}^\beta \le \alpha$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am completely stuck on proving the lemma.

If $\alpha$ is a non-zero ordinal, then there is a largest ordinal $\beta$ such that ${\omega}^\beta \le \alpha$ and $\beta \le \alpha$

I intuitively see that the first statement is true just from the ordinal arithmetic, but I do not see how $\beta \le \alpha$

Comment: Let $\alpha =\omega_1$. What is $\beta$?

Comment: @Stella: $\omega_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah right, less than *or equal to*.

Comment: tmac_balla, what's your explanation for why it's true without the requirement that $\beta\leq\alpha$? I would assume that the same reasoning can be applied to the initial sentiment $S_\alpha=\{\lambda\in ORD:\lambda\leq\alpha\}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\alpha\leq\omega^\alpha$ by an easy induction argument. So you immediately get the inequality.

Comment: (You also need that the map $\beta\mapsto \omega^\beta$ is continuous at limits.)

Comment: (Andres, the definition of exponentiation can be given "directly", but it is painful, and it's much easier to give a recursive definition which is immediately continuous.)

Comment: (Yes, of course. All I meant is that, whether it is an axiom or a theorem, it is needed to ensure the existence of the largest such $\beta$.)

Comment: (Right. Thanks!)